# VBA DIM a string of TEXT to use as part of a value

Tags: vba, public

I am trying to calculate an abbreviation based on a combobox value to use it as part as a value in another module and for some reason the value doesn't transfer to another module at all.

I have it declared as

```
Public MachineLetter As String
```

Above the module in which an if function finds what the actual string should say.

But when I try to reference this MachineLetter in another sub, it doesn't show up. I did try to do the dim and if function inside the actual module in which I currently need it and it did work. So I wonder what's the problem?

Could someone help me finding a solution to this problem?

Comment: Where exactly did you declare MachineLetter? It should be declared in a standard module.

Comment: It is declared in a standard module above all subs and functions. I have such public dims already in my project and all of them work except for this one. The only difference I see with this one is that it's a string this time and not single like the rest of public dims I have.

Comment: Where/when are you setting it's value? Have you possibly declared it more than once? For example, in a function/sub.

Comment: Yup, thanks for your help! Turns out I never called the function to calculate the abbreviation. Thanks for your help! If you post it as an answer, I will gladly check it as correct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check where you've declared `MachineLetter`, it should be declared in a standard module.

Also, make sure you you haven't accidentally declared it more than once, for example in a function/sub. If you do that then it's value will be 'hidden'.

Finally, make sure you are actually setting it's value.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I tested and no problem. When something fells strange try to put a breakpoint to see better the problem.